# SSH to Docker: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: docker, ssh

I'm running a docker container and want to ssh to it using emacs' `tramp` package. I can use `docker exec -it containername bash` successfully. But I just want to use my emacs to do configure work. I've already exposed containers' port 22 to localhost port 22.

By the way, I do have `id_rsa` in my `.ssh` folder.

However, even I use `ssh -p 22 dwolf@localhost` it still doesn't work. The log is as following:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/spacegoing/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/spacegoing/.ssh/config line 26: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: connect to address ::1 port 22: Connection refused
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/spacegoing/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/spacegoing/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'dwolf'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:w7Y3BsQ1xof3U5cohsL5y9ctWvgNaTuXdbDFwQtE+Gc
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/spacegoing/.ssh/known_hosts:26
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/spacegoing/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Add your public key to the docker containers authorized_keys file. `dd if=~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | docker exec -it containername dd of=~/.ssh/authorized_keys` ( This command might not work, tried to one-line it away from a docker host, but the point stands )

Comment: from: ~jpetazzo [If you run SSHD in your Docker containers, you're doing it wrong!](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/)

Comment: @MattClark Many thanks for your help! This method does work!

Comment: @tgogos tks for your reply. I am studying this article it's very helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These three lines:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/spacegoing/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
```

Show that you are offering a public key, but it is being rejected; you are not in the *authorized_keys* file of the target host.

To copy your public key into the docker image, you can use this oneliner, of course, there are many other ways of copying your key into the machine.

```
dd if=~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | docker exec -it containername dd of=~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

As it was pointed out however, your containers should be as small as possible, and ideally do not even need their own SSH servers; but again, everybody's use case is different.

*this command will overwrite any existing authorized keys on the target*

Answer (score 1):

Look at this line:

```
debug1: identity file /Users/spacegoing/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
```

Its looks like you dont have id_rsa key on your device and when

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
```

It cant find it and exiting, try add this key with following commands:

```
cd ~/.ssh/
ssh-keygen id_rsa
```

Then hit enter for all questions and repeat your connection.

Comment: tks for your answer! However I do have that file in my `.ssh` folder. I'm also wondering about that warning :P

Comment: The message `key_load_public: No such file or directory` is not saying that it does not find the private key, but that it is not loading the public key. This is just a warning, and not an error. It can be ignored, it will not prevent connections.